# Is it safe to move a directory that has been bind mounted?

Tags: mount, mv, bind-mount

Say we have a directory that we bind mount to another directory like so

```
mount --bind directory mount-point
```

Later on we move or rename the directory

```
mv directory directory-2
```

What happens when a process attempts to access a file through mount-point? In practice, I found that I could still access all files as normal, but I would like to find either an explicit statement in the documentation or an explanation of the implementation that proves that it is safe or not.

If the behavior is not consistent across unix-like OSs and across filesystems, I am interested particularly in linux and ext4.